# Any risk when using SSL image hosted on another site?

Tags: html, ssl

I'm using **example_image.jpg** which is hosted on a (reputed) site which offers free SSL hosting.

Does this have any security risk?

Comment: What kind of risk are you expecting??

Comment: I'm not really sure! If there is any kind of risks, then I will go ahead and purchase SSL certificate for my own site. So just want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it hasn't. It is a common practice to store images to another server. Edit: You should be sure that you can trust the provider!! If the images are all that you need to forward over a secure path then you will be fine.